# Why is my array wiping after my function executes in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, airtable

I am using the Airtable library in Node.js to make calls to the API. For some reason, when I make a getRecord call, and build an array of the response, the array is coming up empty when I console.log it after the function. When I console.log it inside the function, the array is there as intended. What's going on?

```
var allRecordsList=[]
function getRecord(destinationTable, desiredViewString){
  base(destinationTable).select({
    // Selecting the first 100 records in Grid view:
    maxRecords: 100,
    view: desiredViewString
}).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
    // This function (`page`) will get called for each page of records.
    records.forEach(function(record) {
        allRecordsList.push(record.fields);
    });
    console.log(allRecordsList)
})};

getRecord(usersTable, "Grid view");
console.log(allRecordsList)
```

Comment: Probably because the `.eachPage()` callback is asynchronous which means it happens sometime later so you're attempting to look at the array BEFORE it has been filled.

Comment: Because it's an async operation. If you still want to console it after function call, You can promisify `getRecord` function & use async await for the same.